# Is there a GIS layer file for the USGS Quad Boundaries in NAD27 coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-system

USGS topographic maps currently use the NAD83 coordinate system and all the layer files for the quad boundaries I can find do too. I'm wondering if there exists a nationwide GIS layer for the boundaries of the old NAD27 coordinate system that align with the neatlines for topographic maps pre-1983.

Comment: Can you reproject it back to NAD27 if you have the NAD83 ?

Comment: I *think* you could take the NAD83 one and just redefine it as NAD27. The lat/lon values at the quad corners didn't change between NAD27 and NAD83. If they had transformed the corners, the NAD83 ones would have non-even/standard values.

Comment: According to [this](https://thor-f5.er.usgs.gov/drg/datum_shifts_v2.pdf), I believe the lat/lon values did change. I tried both re-projecting the NAD83 quad boundary to match a NAD27 topo and re-projecting a NAD27 topo geo-tiff ([found here](https://ngmdb.usgs.gov/topoview/viewer/#4/40.01/-100.06)) to match the NAD83 quad boundary layer but they still won't align with each other. Maybe I'm not doing this correctly?